# Two bent arrows one origin tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

For linguistic syntax analysis I need two bent arrows with the same origin but different end.

What I have is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\textbf{baab}  \ar[bend left=50]{r}{RDP} &  baa\textbf{baab} \ar[bend left=19]{r} \ar[bend left=60]{r}{\textsc{rdp}} & po.\textbf{tambaambaabu}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

However, I would need the second two arrows to start at the same origin, and then the first arrow should reach the first `mb` sequence of `tambaambaabu` and the second arrow should point at the second sequence of `mb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `start anchor` and choose the same one for both paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\textbf{baab}  \ar[bend left=50]{r}{RDP} &  
baa\textbf{baab} \ar[start anchor=north,end anchor=160,bend left=19]{r} 
\ar[start anchor=north,end anchor=50,bend left=60]{r}{\textsc{rdp}} & 
po.\textbf{tambaambaabu}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats great, thank you. Though it would be very important to have the tips or the arrows each pointing exactly to its specific destination. Can that be done with ```anchor``` as well?

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi Of course, you can specify the `end anchor` as well. What do you mean by "specific destination"? (Will be offline for a short while now.)

Comment: the sepcific destination as in "the first arrow should reach the first mb sequence of tambaambaabu and the second arrow should point at the second sequence of mb"

Comment: I found the solution like this:  ```\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\textbf{baab}  \ar[bend left=50]{r}{RDP} &  
baa\textbf{baab} \ar[start anchor=north,bend left=60, end anchor=30]{r} 
\ar[start anchor=north,bend left=60, end anchor=150]{r}{\textsc{rdp}} & 
po.\textbf{tambaambaabu}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}```